# Hiding text/links with 0 value results by php

Tags: php, mysql, show-hide

I have a list of links in my html table, like: Bra: 5psc, Brasets: 15pcs, Blanket: 0pcs, Towel: 0pcs. I need that "Blanket" and "Towel" and other list positions" with 0 value hiding from list until they 0 value, after value change to more than 0pcs (for example: 1pcs or more) they would shown. "Blanket: 0pcs" and "Towel: 0pcs" and "other goods" with 0pcs value not hiding but still show 0pcs value. What i'm doing wrong or what my mistake? Maybe there is another way to do this. I can't understand. Thank you for help.

```
<?
  $resultonshafa = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE shafa='Y'");
  $resultonshafasaled = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE shafa='Y' and saled='Y'");
  $resultonolx = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE last_name='Y'");
  $resultonolxsaled = mysql_query("SELECT count(customers_id) from tbl_customers WHERE last_name='Y' and saled='Y'");

  $topmenuOnShafa = mysql_result($resultonshafa, 0);
  $topmenuNotOnShafa = mysql_result($resultonshafasaled, 0);
  $topmenuOnOlx = mysql_result($resultonolx, 0);
  $topmenuNotOnOlx = mysql_result($resultonolxsaled, 0);

  $topmenuOnOlxText = "Blanket : ";
  $topmenuOnShafaText = "Towel : ";
 ?>

<?php if ($topmenuNotOnOlx!=0): ?>
<span class="saled-warning"><a href="some_link" target="_self"><?=$topmenuNotOnOlx;?></a></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($topmenuOnOlx!=0): ?><?=$topmenuOnOlxText;?><?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($topmenuOnOlx!=0): ?>
<a href="some_link" target="_self"><?=$topmenuOnOlx;?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($topmenuNotOnShafa!=0): ?>
<span class="saled-warning"><a href="some_link" target="_self">
<?=$topmenuNotOnShafa;?></a></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i think preg_much() could help you with this. Filter the values and if you find one character you dont want replace it

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Thank you very much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just run a single query to get all of that information:

```
SELECT
   SUM(shafa='Y') AS only_shafa,
   SUM(shafa='Y' AND saled='Y') as saled_and_shafa,
   SUM(last_name='Y') AS only_lastname,
   SUM(last_name='y' AND saled='Y') AS saled_and_lastname
FROM ...
```

MySQL will auto-convert the boolean true/false returned by those =/and tests into integers, and add them up. Then you only run this ONE query, fetch a single row of results:

```
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
```

And then test for those values with `$row['only_salend']` and the like.

But note that your code simply assumes queries never fail. That is a BAD assumption. if the query fails, you get boolean `FALSE` returned. You would then try to get a result from that false, causing ANOTHER false. And since your results are now boolean FALSE, `false != 0` will evaluate to (falsely) evaluate to boolean `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Hard to me, but very perfect sample.